# Nose does not run tests

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

Suppose you have a python package named A with the following directory structure

```
A
├── B.py
└── __init__.py
```

where `__init__.py` is empty and the content of `B.py` is given by

```
def test_B():
    assert False
```

Running nose on the simple package above misses the test

```
$ nosetests A

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

One has to run

```
$ nosetests A/B.py
```

in order to catch the test, but that 
quickly becomes unwieldy if one has a complicated submodule structure inside A.

How can one make nose run all functions starting with 'test' in package A without having to specify every single file in which they occur?

Comment: Are those your actual files names?

Comment: `nose` also follows a convention about filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--all-modules` flag:

```
$ nosetests A --all-modules
```

Answer (score 1):

As @sobolevn pointed out, nose follows a [convention about filenames](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#extended-usage):

> nose collects tests automatically from python source files, directories and packages found in its working directory (which defaults to the current working directory). Any python source file, directory or package that matches the testMatch regular expression (by default: (?:^|[b_.-])[Tt]est) will be collected as a test (or source for collection of tests).

You could rename `B.py` to `test_B.py` for instance.

Comment: B.py also contains the function that is being tested so renaming the module would not be an option. I chose to place the tests in the same file rather than a seperate test_.py.

Comment: @dzhelil In that case, gregb answer is definitely the way to go. However, it is a good practice to separate your tests from the code (`A/test/test_B.py` for instance)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem today with python 3.8.

Turns out that adding a file `setup.cfg` in the root of the test folder solves the problem.

Example:

```
|code
|  | __init__.py
|  | A.py
|tests
|  | setup.cfg
|  | test_A.py
```

Contents of `setup.cfg` should be:

```
[nosetests]
traverse-namespace=1
```

Now running `nosetests tests` will work.